# Too many Insert Conflicts in sync framework when the same data exists on both client and server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I request you to understand the problem we are facing with Sync for which I need your help and guide.

What we have:
1) 50 tables to be sync-ed, divided into 6 common scopes and 8 template based scopes(parameterized based on CLIENTID column of CLIENT table).
2) Sync is to be done from different PCs to SQL Azure
3) From C# WPF App, we select a client(CLIENTID), run sync set-up(provisioning) and then start sync process using method.

Issue we face very often:
1) Few clients are already sync-ed, on a n-th client, due to network connectivity issue / timeout issue, app needs to be closed. When we run provision on that particular client again, sometime we get exception that Selectchanges or bulkInsert is missing.

2) If the above happens, we de-StoreProvision, then re-provision. That leaves us with client and server having the same set of data. If we proceed with sync then, it takes 7 hours to complete erroring out with lots of INSERT CONFLICTS.

So, when in the mid of syncing, network connectivity fails, COMMIT happens with scopes that ran successfully? Or, few scopes that ran well leave us with partial syncing?
Is there any way of getting rid of numbers of Insert Conflicts except e-provision and re-provision?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the transaction scope in sync framework scopes is at the scope level. if synching a scope and its aborted for some reason, all changes applied by that scope gets rolled back.

if you have 3 scopes and one of them fails, only that scope is rolled back, the other two is committed.

when you deprovision, do you deprovision/reprovision the entire store or only that specific scope?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I understand what you mean. In past I was deprovisioning the entire store, but now I de-provision specific scopes(including the common scopes). Problem is, during setup, my app crashed or net connectivity went to dogs, I tried setup+sync again but got error messages like http://screencast.com/t/bgwWyw6PQF, trouble came thereafter. I had to deprovision and re-provision specific scopes. That left me with taking up 5 times more time with lots of insert conflicts. Is there any script that I can run on SQL to make client and server understand that it is already sync-ed?

Comment: Another error when setup failed and I tried to sync again. http://screencast.com/t/aAPeAjf5JfP

Comment: you should enable sync fx tracing to get more detailed error. there is no sql script to generate the sync knowledge of what has been synched. if you know the client and server has same data, you can try intercepting the changes in the changesselected event on first sync and remove the rows from the change dataset. this will make sync fx think it synched without applying any change.

Comment: Hello @JuneT Thanks we are getting closer to the actual issue. I am novish, please tell me how do I ascertain of First Sync and intercept the changes in the changesselected event and how to remove the rows from the change dataset? Which method gets me changed dataset?

Comment: the sync knowledge column on the scope will be empty in the scope_info table... to intercept changes, see: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/